# SonarQube5.6.6 not display issue details

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

[image]

Hi, After running sonarqube, I am able to get the summary of the issues, but when clicking on the filter for the issue details, I am getting No Issues.
Can someone hellp me out here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you try to reset the elastic search working dir ?